# Point static content like css and js to cookieless subdomain

Tags: performance, subdomains, customization

How can I change the links that WordPress generates for all static content like css, js, png, jpg, gif, etc to a cookieless subdomain? I don't want to use mod_rewrite. I want the PHP code to replace `www` with `s0` in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a fantastic plugin called [CDN Linker](https://github.com/wmark/CDN-Linker).